# How do I test that a given shell has been executed in Python?

Tags: python, linux, pytest, ptrace

I want to test a Python function that executes a shell command.

According to [testfixtures](https://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/popen.html) there are two approaches:

- execute a real process and check the result
- mock the subprocess module and check the expected interactions

My function is called `run_in_shell`. Although the subprocess module is the obvious way to implement it, my function doesn't explicitly depend on it, so I'm trying to do the "real" test.

```py
import subprocess

def run_in_shell(command, shell_name=None):
    """Run command in default shell. Use named shell instead if given."""
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True, executable=shell_name)
```

This test shows that the function can execute a command with the default shell.

```py
import pytest

def test_with_command_string(capfd):
    run_in_shell("echo 'hello'")
    cap = capfd.readouterr()
    assert cap.out.strip() == "hello"
    assert cap.err.strip() == ""
```

I also want to show that it can execute in the user's chosen shell such as `/bin/bash`.

The invocation is simple enough. This prints `hello` to the terminal.

```py
run_in_shell("echo 'hello'", shell_name="/bin/bash")
```

Without mocking, how do I show that it executed `/bin/bash` to do so?

I tried [ptracer](https://ptracer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to trace the system calls, but the output disappointed me.

```py
def callback(syscall):
    name = syscall.name
    args = ",".join([str(a.value) for a in syscall.args])
    print(f"{name}({args})")

with ptracer.context(callback):
    run_in_shell("echo 'hello'")

with ptracer.context(callback):
    run_in_shell("echo 'hello'", shell_name="/bin/bash")
```

I was hoping to see a `clone` or `fork` call with the name of the shell, but there is nothing so clear. I don't understand the strings in the `read` calls, and I don't see any `write` calls.

```
hello
pipe2((23, 24),524288)
clone(18874385,0,None,261939,0)
close(24)
read(23,bytearray(b'U\r\r\n'),50000)
close(23)
wait4(262130,0,0,None)

hello
pipe2((24, 25),524288)
clone(18874385,0,None,261939,0)
futex(2,129,1,0,9693984,9694016)
futex(0,129,1,0,None,9694016)
close(25)
read(24,bytearray(b'\x1d'),50000)
close(24)
wait4(262308,0,0,None)
```

At this point I'm out of my depth. I've surely misunderstood what the system calls are really doing. What am I missing?

Is it possible and practical to test this using Python and PyTest? If not, I'll redefine my function to depend explicitly on one of the subprocess functions, and then I can use a mock to test that it sends the right messages to the function.

Comment: Using [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Teejay Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77010592) shows, you can use the command to introspect the shell. The shell already stores its name in the `$0` variable, so you can just echo that and check the standard output.

```py
def test_executes_in_specified_shell(stack, capfd):
    run_in_shell("echo $0", shell_name="/bin/bash")
    cap = capfd.readouterr()
    assert cap.out.strip() == "/bin/bash"
    assert cap.err.strip() == ""
```

I think `$0` should work in any POSIX-compliant shell, although I can't find clear documentation for that. It certainly works in [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) and [dash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, for this check all we're trying to do is verify that whatever shell is passed in is being used.

I would keep it as simple as possible and just print the active shell's name, then verify it matches the target shell. Something like

```
def test_executes_in_specified_shell(capfd):
    target_shell = "/bin/bash" 
    
    print_current_shell = "ps -p $$ -oargs= && true"
    run_in_shell(print_current_shell, shell_name=target_shell)

    cap = capfd.readouterr()
    current_shell = cap.out.strip()
    assert current_shell == target_shell
```

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of running an introspective command to test that. Can you elaborate on `-oargs=`? That's new to me and seems to be the key to this. I'm going to try it tomorrow when I'm back at my desk!

Comment: It doesn't work but I don't know why! `bash -c 'ps -p $$ -oargs='` gives `ps -p 553355 -oargs=`, as if `$$` gave the pid of the `ps` process. But `bash -c 'ps -p $$ -oargs= && true'` gives `bash -c ps -p $$ -oargs= && true`, which starts with `bash` so looks right. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Your insight helped me find an even easier way. I'll share it in an answer.

Comment: [Bash replaces itself with the simple command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755419/why-doesnt-pid-refer-to-bash-here), so `ps` would return its own command. The `&& true` addition makes the command a compound and bash forks each subprocess with a new pid.

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works!

Comment: I completed your example so that it is also a valid solution. Thanks again for your help.